# Пустой вывод Django

Tags: python, django, шаблоны

Учусь работать с отношениями в Django.
Добавил данные в БД, но при запросе ничего не выводит

Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="list-group">
    {% for i in employee_list.positions.all %}
        {{ i.fullname }}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Модель:

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.

class Position(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)


class Employee(models.Model):
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    position = models.ManyToManyField(Position, related_name='positions')
    wage_rate = models.SmallIntegerField(max_length=30)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    chief = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='children', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fullname

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Работник'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Работники'
```

views

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView
from .models import Employee, Position


class EmployeeView(ListView):
    model = Employee


class PositionView(ListView):
    model = Position
```

Как это решить и почему так происходит?

Comment: Вы передаёте в шаблон переменную `employee_list` что в ней содержится?

Comment: Где ваша views? возможно там ошибка

Comment: Нужны ваши views, без них пока неясно, как вы данные отправляете в шаблон.

Comment: Используйте ответы для указания ошибки, показа способа решения проблемы и т.д.
Если вы хотите что-то уточнить, получить больше информации, то пишите комментарии.

Comment: from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView
from .models import Employee, Position


class EmployeeView(ListView):
    model = Employee


class PositionView(ListView):
    model = Position

Comment: добавил views в пост

Answer (score 2, accepted):

views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# Create your views here.
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView
from .models import Employee, Position

def employee_view(request):
    all = Employee.objects.all()
    context = { "all": all }
return render(request, 'path_to_template/template' , context)
```

template :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="list-group">
    {% for i in all %}
        {{ i.fullname }}
        {{ i.position}}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Должно сработать, но я не проверял

Answer (score 1):

Моя ошибка заключалась в том, что я делал запрос сразу у нескольких пользователей, а нужно было к одному (надеюсь понятно объяснил)
Так же прошу прощения, что не верно выразил то, что мне нужно

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="list-group">
    {% for i in employee_list %}
        {% for pl in i.positions.all %}
            {{ pl }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]